# class not found add jar via eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, exception, classnotfoundexception

When I was working with java spring hibernate struts2 eclipse project. I used buildpath-> addjar option to add jars from a folder inside the workspace. Even if the class is available it shows class not found exception.

If i put those jar files in web-inf/lib folder everything works.. Should i keep those files in the lib itself? Can i just include those jars in a seperate folder and add jar using eclipse configure build path??

what is the problem ? please help me... thanks in advance...

Comment: Please answer me if any one knows what the real problem is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a standard Eclipse **Dynamic web project**, best way to go is to put all your Jars in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder. This will automatically add them to your build path and also include them in your WAR when you export it.

If you still want to use the **Build Path > Add Jar** option on the project, and want your Jars to also be included in your WAR, you have to go to the **Project Properties > Deployment Assembly** configuration and include them there. Of course this is double the work for every Jar.

Comment: @betomontejo I am using Java project with similar scenario. so i cannot reach Dynamic Web Project Option. Any idea how to make it work?